# Convergence of series with sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a continuous mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{K} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is a compact convex set.

Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and, for all $k \geq 0$, define $a_i := \alpha^i$ (so that $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = \alpha$, $a_2 = \alpha^2$, and so on).

Now consider some arbitrary $x^0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the iteration 
$$ x^{k+1} := \frac{1}{ \left(\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i \right) } \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i \ f\left( x^i \right). $$

Clearly, for $\alpha = 0$ we have $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{i} = 0$ for all $i\geq 1$. Therefore $x^{k} = x^{0}$ for all $k \geq 0$.

I would like to prove the following claim. There exists $\alpha > 0$ such that $x^{k}$ converges to some $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x^{k} = \bar{x}$ for some $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

If this is the case, I would like to quantify (estimate) such $\alpha>0$ dependending on (how big is) $\mathcal{K}$.

Comment: If $\alpha=0$ then $x^k = f(x^0)$ for all $k$. At first glance, your equation is bounded by the maximum of magnitude of elements in the compact set. Thus the sequence evolves inside of a compact ball of that radius, and has a subsequential limit. You might start there. Also if $K$ is also convex, then $x^k$ is in $K$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that since the range of $f$ lies inside of a compact set, we have that $\sup_{y \in Ran(f)} \|y\| \le M$. Thus for any choice of points $z_1, z_2, z_3, ...$ the series converges: $$\left\|\sum_{i=0}^\infty \alpha^i f(z_i)\right\| \le M \sum_{i=0}^\infty \alpha^i = \frac{M}{1-\alpha}.$$

Now since the series converges absolutely, the series converges (from the theory of Banach spaces). The sum on top of your recursive formula is dominated by a sum of this type, and so converges as well.

Note that $\alpha$ does not depend on $\mathcal{K}$ at all, only on the fact that $\mathcal{K}$ is bounded. Though the rate of convergence does depend on $\mathcal{K}$.

Comment: I should mention that here we are keeping $\alpha <1$.

Comment: What if $\alpha=1$?

Comment: Moreover, can you please be more explicit (precise) in the answer?

Comment: If $\alpha = 1$ then there are no guarantees. Well according to my approach. You might look for a counter example.

Comment: I'll add more later to the answer.